# Graphical representation of data in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am a newbie in flex.

Latest task is to generate a graph or a netwrok based on the data input.

What is the best way to do it. Also when clicked on a node of a network it should show the associated data with that node.

Hope to get some help soon!

Thanks,
Kartik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a license to flex builder pro to use the Flex Graphing components.  You can see what components are available with example code from this link

http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/componentexplorer/explorer.html

Open the data visualization folder to get to the charts.

Comment: I have the full version of Fb pro. So do I still go by the flex component explorer or is there any other thing. I may not be able to use the graphics lib as a pro. Can you suggest me?

Comment: you can use the component explorer to investigate what charts are available. You could also copy the mxml and use it as a starting point. If you have the FB pro license you have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/